# The photo uploaded by the user is not saved in the media directory

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-media

If I enter the image manually in the admin panel, it is correct, but if it is entered through the form, it is not saved in the media directory.

views.py

```
def profile_additional_info(request):
   if request.method == "POST":
        first_name = request.POST['first_name']
        last_name = request.POST['last_name']
        email = request.POST['email']
        phone_number = request.POST['phone_number']
        photo_prof = request.FILES['photo_prof']
        kod_meli = request.POST['kod_meli']
        shomare_kart = request.POST['shomare_kart']
   ...
     
   if photo_prof:
       Profile.objects.all().filter(user=request.user).update(
                                         photo_prof=photo_prof)
   ...            
   
   else:
        prof_user = Profile(user=request.user, photo_prof=photo_prof, 
                                phone_number=phone_number,
                                    kod_meli=kod_meli, 
                                shomare_kart=shomare_kart)
        prof_user.save()
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    ...
    photo_prof=models.ImageField(max_length=10000,upload_to='photo/%y/%m/%d/',blank=True)
    ...
```

template:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'profile_additional_info' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
    <input name="photo_prof" type="file" class="custom-file-input"id="inputGroupFile04"
 aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon04">
...
</form>
```

settings:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I found [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57594348/how-to-pass-image-to-requests-post-in-python) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70473911/how-can-i-upload-an-image-to-database-via-html-form-in-django#comment124788562_70590732) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70473911/how-can-i-upload-an-image-to-database-via-html-form-in-django#comment124788562_70590732) on SO
but none of them solved my problem.

Comment: `I put MEDIAROOT, MEDIAURL in settings` please show these settings. And show some more code from the view. If form class is involved - please show this class definition.

Comment: I sent the things you requested and the form class is not involved with the code

Answer (score 0):

> [update()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update) does an update at the SQL level and, thus, does not call any save() methods on your models, nor does it emit the pre_save or post_save signals (which are a consequence of calling Model.save())

Files are not stored in DB, only file paths are stored there. `update` can only update rows in DB, not files. Thus (actually I never tried to do like this) given code

`Profile.objects.all().filter(user=request.user).update(photo_prof=photo_prof)`

cannot modify files on drive and just updates the path in DB which will be pointing to nowhere.

[Basic file updloads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads) examples in the Django docs don't suggest to *run updates*, they suggest to instantiate the model and save it. In your case I guess the `Profile` already exists and you need to update the picture. Try this code (after if):

```
profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=request.user)
profile.photo_prof = photo_prof
profile.save()
```

You already did some research on SO - here are [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041232/django-delete-filefield/16041527#16041527) [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39384417/it-is-possible-for-django-to-upload-file-without-forms) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62050397/issues-in-uploading-image-from-user-without-django-modelform) you might want to look into. As said in the last one it is recommended to start using forms. They do lots of work for you.